# When is a question deemed 'unsalvagable'?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I was reviewing some posts and I ran into one question in particular which made me question where is the line between 'should be improved' and 'unsalvagable'? 
 
 The OP seemed to get the right idea across in regards to wanting to know about a topic around CSS3 but there was

- No code
- Sentences were not formatted correctly as apposed to the standard on SO
- Several spelling mistakes

I can totally see why another reviewer would look at it and determine the question unsalvagable, it was not clear or concise but to me and some other reviewers i'd know what the user was trying to say. Is there a kind of minimum to what you could classify as unsalvagable? I believe this question can be improved by a comment.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

That's exactly what <kbd>Unsalvageable</kbd> > <kbd>Should be closed...</kbd> > <kbd>Unclear what you're asking</kbd> is for.

"Unsalvageable" doesn't mean that the question will be destroyed forever and ever, without giving any chance to the OP to improve it. In this case, the question would be closed, showing the OP useful links to teach him/her how to improve it, so it can be reopened and answered.

If you choose "Should be improved", the question will be sent to a queue where *the community* will try to edit and improve it. Formatting and spelling mistakes can be addressed there, but the question would still be unclear. If the OP is the only one able to clarify the question, it should be closed until then.

Comment: just what i was looking for. brilliant!

Comment: Anyone else find this UI unclear?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Apparently, [everyone does](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292316/is-anyone-else-seeing-repairable-questions-in-the-help-improvement-queue).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It took me almost a thousand reviews to completely understand the distinction. I'm not proud of that.

Answer (score 8):

If you understand what the question is about *and* fully understand what is asked *and* it is not otherwise close-worthy/off-topic, then it should be reviewed as **Should be improved**. The reasoning being, if you understand the question in Triage and it is fully fixable by an edit of a user who is not the OP, then it's likely that other users who encounter this question eventually in the *Help and Improvement* review queue can improve it enough that it's a good question.

There is still a chance that other Triage reviewers don't agree with you, so it might still be closed.

If you're unsure whether it is unsalvageable or improvable, there is nothing wrong with **Skip**ing it.

Comment: great follow on advice from the current answers provided!

Comment: Yeah, there are still problems with the new review path (Triage queue > Help and Improvement queue), so others still give advice to use the old path (Triage queue > Close votes > "Edit" > Reopen queue).

Answer (score 1):

If I'd vote to close a question I judge it to be unsalvagable in the Triage review queue.

Comment: Would it just be safe to close the question and expect that the user will ask a better one? If it's within the criteria of being unsalvagable?

Comment: That's what I would do. Inside the Triage review queue, the options behind "unsalvagable" are the usual close options. So I'd use them like I use close options on a normal question.

Comment: Great advice, thankyou.

Comment: @BradleyWilson: Iff the OP improves his question enough so it's answerable, it will be re-opened. The reopen-queue (first edit by OP or any reopen-vote sends it there) is always virtually empty.