# Is anyone else seeing repairable questions in the Help & Improvement Queue?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, help-improvement

I've tried out the HIQ a few times. I can't find anything to do except click the link for 'no, not salvageable after all'. And I don't even get badge credit for that. Some process, or set of misguided reviewers, is delivering a very large number of questions here that do not belong. If there are any that could be [licked into shape](http://bestiary.ca/beasts/beast171.htm), they seem to be completely hidden in the midden.

Is the problem here people taking the wrong choice in triage, or does something else populate in here?

Comment: I like trying out new features, but I gave up after spending an hour in the queue, and only being able to edit ***8*** posts.  It just seems like a pointless exercise.  I couldn't figure out how some people could survive in there for so long, and review upwards of  *1200* of them, but it turns out [some people just aren't as picky at editing as I am](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29987885/revisions)

Comment: The behavior of the "doesn't belong here" button doesn't even seem consistent: sometimes it raises a flag, sometimes not, often it's disputed in obvious cases where only the op could ever fix it.  So I've given up even doing that in the queue.

Comment: this looks like a deliberate design decision to set up Triage and H&I play ping-pong. SE team likely can't find other way to [keep garbage questions invisible](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287466/help-improve-the-help-improvement-queue/291919#comment184593_291919): plain closing will push them to front page and deletion will likely cause inexperienced askers repost. See [Is the “Help and Improvement” queue just bad-question purgatory?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291741/839601)

Comment: I've abandoned it as a waste of time. Almost all questions I see should either a) be closed immediately, or b) can only be improved by the author (see (a)). There are plenty of close-worthy questions without mucking about in the HIQ.

Comment: As the HIQ demonstrates, the majority of triage reviewers have no idea what they're doing. The same was true for the suggested edits queue, until SE "improved" the situation by redefining (== drastically lowering) the standars for suggested edits. Let's hope the same doesn't happen for questions as well.

Comment: Would it help if the triage queue had an option for "needs-improvement-that-only-the-author-can-provide"?

Comment: @l4mpi Well, to give them *some* credit, the instructions/guidelines for triage actively encourage people to mark unsalvagable content as NI.  I don't doubt that there are a lot of bad reviewers, or that we wouldn't have this problem even if the instructions would have been better from the start, but many of them are technically following the [flawed] instructions they were given.

Comment: @Foon It already has it; it's called Unsalvageable, specifically, closing as Unclear (or occasionally one of the other close reasons).

Comment: Can you write out "HIQ" in full please? I don't know what it is.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The tag isn't a sufficient clue?

Comment: Triage is largely to blame. I tend to go back and check at least some posts to see if the other reviewers concurred, especially Unsalvageable. I get overruled at least a couple times a day on classic Unsalvageable questions that three reviewers mark as Should Be Improved. [Random Recent Example](http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7928921). Most triage reviewers aren't distinguishing things that require OP fixing from things H&I queue can fix (grammar, spelling, formatting, etc).

Comment: A repairable question in HIQ is rarer that a unicorn.

Comment: Just to reiterate my point. I have **23 disputed**, 54 helpful, 14 waiting for review, and 0 declined flags (excluding spam). Want to guess in which queue I flagged those **disputed flags**? Triage. I had none disputed until I started Triage reviewing. They are disputed because the plurality did not agree with me. That's a lot of disputed flags. Many of those are no-brainer Unsalvageable.

Comment: @bmargulies: I think we can do better than "clues". :)

Comment: @MarkBalhoff: I've gotten roughly a hundred disputed flags from Triage in the last month and a half or so. Good times.

Answer (score 41):

> Is the problem here people taking the wrong choice in triage?

Yes.

(Although you could also claim that a core problem is poor guidance of the Triage queue about what items should be marked as Needs Improvement vs Unsalvagable, among other indirect causes, but the *direct* cause is simply people taking the wrong action in Triage.)

Comment: I'm frankly not convinced its entirely the directions-in-Triage's fault. I think that the target of HIQ is so small its not realistic because HIQ expects all the work to be done by some random SOer. Realistically most of HIQ can't be done without a 2-way conversation.

Comment: Per my comment on main post, I generally agree. I would say the triage guidance exists and is solid but not readily visible. The problem is the guidance is scattered across a few dozen meta posts (basis for my reviews) and is not summarized in any prominent fashion (or at all) on the review page. As far as I've been able to grasp, it basically boils down to: Looks OK aka "Only Problem is Lack of OP Effort", Should Be Improved - Needs Formatting, Spelling, Grammar Etc. (OP Input Not Needed), Unsalvageable - Needs OP to Redeem (Too Broad, Primarily Opinion, Unclear, Missing Error/Code).

Comment: @DavidGrinberg: [I'm pretty well convinced that it's Triage's fault.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290977/1079354)  But hopefully that will get iterated on quickly and we can see improvements from it sooner.

Comment: @Makoto The irony is that I asked that question :)

Answer (score 14):

A lot of people forget that Triage predates H&I by several weeks (when it was unclear what the button would do), and there's nothing to tell people in Triage that

> Hey, if I click **Needs Improvement** it sends it to the H&I queue for editing.

More importantly, you have the scary `Unsalvageable` button which pops up a combo Flag/Close box, again without clear guiadance. It's sad, because I don't see H&I as broken. Triage just doesn't present its options as well as it needs to. As long as the disconnect between Triage and H&I exists, H&I will remain nothing but a cesspool of bad threads.