# Review Triage - What should I do if the question requires information from the OP?

Tags: discussion, support, bug, triage

**This is not a duplicate of the marked question!** Please note that this question is not about whether "Requires Editing" is appropriate if the editing needs to be done by the OP (it is not). This question asks what **should** be done by reviewers in that case.

I realise similar questions to this have been [asked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319128/triage-review-queue-inconsistent-guidelines-for-requires-editing) [before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289738/suggestion-for-rewording-of-triage-review-guidance). However even after going through those answers I still feel stuck.

As I discovered today, there are three places that describe the appropriate use of the **Requires Editing** button on the Triage page:

1. The tooltip on the button itself:

   > this question could be good, but requires some time and attention of our editors
2. The text in the "more" dropdown:

   > for questions where edits by the author or others would result in a question that is clear and answerable
3. The text in the [linked answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue/295674#295674) (which I won't quote because there's a lot there).

For ages I only referred to the "more" dropdown if I was unsure about the use of a button. I didn't realise the tooltip existed, and I didn't feel the need to click the link since it seemed like the "more" dropdown covered it pretty well. This means I've clicked **Requires Editing** for a *lot* of questions that needed to be edited by their author. Today I noticed the tooltip and also realised I hadn't clicked the link yet, so had a look at it. I was somewhat horrified to realise that, according to the linked answer, I've been using **Requires Editing** wrong the whole time. I gather that's a *Bad Thing™* because it puts the question into a queue for reviewers to review/edit, and if they can't edit the post it wastes their time. This, in and of itself, needs to be rectified immediately, however it's not the point of this post.

The issue I'm having is that I now don't know what to do if a post needs to be edited by its author (usually to add additional information) but will be a good post otherwise. Triage inherently presents recently-asked questions to us, and there's often a comment already on the question asking the OP to edit the question with a specific additional piece of information. In that case the OP may not have had a chance to respond to the comment and/or edit their question.

So this is my dilemma:

- **Looks OK**: Nope, it doesn't look ok... it might in future but not yet, and if they don't end up editing their post it won't look ok.
- **Requires Editing**: *Perfect*... except I recently discovered this shouldn't be used if the OP has to do the editing.
- **Unsalvageable**: Well no, it's very salvageable. All it needs is a bit more info from the OP. I also have no idea what flag I would use in this case.
- **Skip**: The easy way out... but the question will then go onto someone else. What are *they* supposed to do? Skip as well? Just keep skipping until eventually the OP edits the question?

I'm stuck. I don't know what to do in these cases and it's not clear from any of the information I could find on the Triage page. Can someone clear this up for me? (And can the SO devs please remove the contradictions in the **Requires Editing** "more" downdown text? That's what the "bug" tag is for.)

Comment: If any of the hold flags apply to the question in its current state, choose Unsalvageable and pick the appropriate flag reason. Don't worry about what edits the OP might make later: who knows if they'll ever make the edits at all and if they do make the edits, that should prevent the question from actually getting placed on hold.

Comment: I'm rather surprised that so many people marked this as a duplicate. It's not a dupe of that question! It really isn't. Please READ the question!

Comment: Specifically I'm not asking if I should use the Requires Editing button (I can see now I've been using it wrong for ages), rather my question is _what do I do instead?_

Comment: The FAQ itself would have been a better duplicate. It does have this in its answer: *...but omits specific errors and/or logcat listing, the question doesn't require editing - it requires more information, so choose Unsalvageable->should be closed->unclear what you're asking.* (I actually looked for it when I left the earlier comment but managed to miss it; otherwise I would have suggested it.)

Comment: @Blackwood Good edit, I likey :) :thumbsup:

Comment: @BSMP Where is that page? I don't know what to search for in the FAQ.

Comment: It's actually the link for number 3 in your question. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue/295674#295674 Last lines of the "Do not" paragraph under Requires Editing.

Comment: @BSMP Oh well damn, it was right there in plain sight the whole time. I must be blind. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: related: [How long should we wait for a poster to clarify a question before closing?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260265/839601) <--- This is what you do in Triage: Unsalvageable -> Should be closed -> Unclear

Comment: @gnat Thanks, that's a useful post.

Comment: Also relevant: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292251/when-is-a-question-deemed-unsalvagable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you should only choose Requires Editing if other users than the OP can edit it into a good question. This is because posts reviewed as Requires Editing go into the [Help and Improvement review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper) available for 2k users, where the reviewer has two options: edit or skip. [The Help and Improvement queue is currently having big problems](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291562/4284627) because many users don't quite understand how to use the Requires Editing button, they use it for questions that can only be edited by the OP, so the users who review Help and Improvement can't do anything about the post. I can't blame the users who don't use Requires Editing correctly, since, as you stated in your question, the way they're using it is what it says to do in the "more" dropdown. The problem is that the "more" dropdown is wrong. It should be changed to "for questions where edits by other users than the author would result in a question that is clear and answerable".

If you get a question in Triage which can only be good if edited by the OP, you should choose Unsalvageable and choose the flag which fits best for that question. You can also leave a comment explaining to the OP how to make their question better. If the question is closed and then the OP edits it to turn it into a good question, it will enter the reopen queue and be reopened.

Comment: Oh really? If they edit the question it could be reopened? I feel like I may have known that long ago, but I had totally forgotten. That's very useful information. I can see the "more" dropdown is wrong. That's _Super Bad™_ because I would assume many people would do like me and only read that. The second paragraph of your answer goes very close to answering my question... except what flag should I use if the question is just missing some information? None of the flags fit that situation. "too broad" and "unclear what you're asking" are closest, but neither is a good fit.

Comment: @Clonkex What flag to use really depends on the question, but in most cases I would probably say either "unclear what you're asking" or "off-topic because missing a minimal, complete and verifiable example". Anyway, if you flag the question as Should be closed and the question is closed, your flag will be marked helpful no matter if you chose the same reason as the one that the question was closed for or a different reason. So as long as you select a Should be closed flag, don't worry too much about what flag to use.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. And yeah ok, I forgot the MCVE flag existed. Good info, thanks, that alleviates my concerns.